# Como instalar as dependências de um projeto Durandal usando Mimosa?

Tags: front-end, dependências, durandal

Deixa eu explicar a pergunta. Eu saberia a resposta se a pergunta fosse:

```
"Como instalar as dependências de um projeto Laravel usando Composer?"
```

No mundo do PHP, usando o [**Composer**](https://getcomposer.org), a gente pode criar um projeto a partir de um esqueleto pronto, usando o comando [`composer create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project). No caso do *framework* [**Laravel**](http://laravel.com/), podemos criar um projeto com o comando:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

Da mesma forma, no mundo do *front-end*, usando [**Mimosa**](http://mimosa.io), a gente pode criar um projeto a partir de um esqueleto pronto, usando o comando [`mimosa skel:new`](http://mimosa.io/commands.html#skel). No caso do *framework* [**Durandal**](http://durandaljs.com), podemos criar um projeto com o comando:

```
mimosa skel:new durandal
```

Em ambos os casos, o "esqueleto" é obtido de um repositório (no [GitHub](https://github.com) ou [outro local](https://bitbucket.org)) devidamente registrado (no [Packagist](https://packagist.org) ou [outro local](https://github.com/dbashford/skelmimosa/blob/master/registry.json)), e em seguida as dependências são automaticamente processadas e instaladas.

Mas ao copiar o projeto para outro lugar, não copiamos a parafernália toda das dependências junto (a pasta `vendors` ou equivalente). Copiamos apenas os arquivos do projeto. (Há um `.gitignore` que deixa essa parafernália fora dos *commits*.)

Pois bem: com o projeto copiado para outro local, no caso do Composer, o comando para torná-lo utilizável é:

```
composer install
```

Este é o comando que `create-project` executa automaticamente após obter o esqueleto.

A minha pergunta é: **qual o comando para instalar as dependências de um projeto** no caso do Mimosa? Qual é o comando que é executado automaticamente após a obtenção do esqueleto? O que eu preciso rodar na minha cópia para deixar igual ao original, após `skel:new`?

Comment: Utilize o `MooTools` para emitir um Mugido e atrair a `Mimosa`, espere ela chegar até você. Logo após disto, peça para que ela instale as dependências do `Durandal`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Originalmente esta resposta foi escrita em inglês e o autor com as melhores intenções de ajudar desculpou-se por não conseguir responde-la em português.*

---

Vi o tráfego a partir desta questão afluindo para o site do Mimosa e gostaria de tentar ajudá-lo.

`mimosa skel:new` apenas faz um `git clone`.  https://github.com/dbashford/skelmimosa/blob/master/src/command/new.coffee#L51

Se você executar `mimosa skel:new durandal durandal` você vai ter um projeto Durandal dentro de uma pasta durandal.

Dentro dessa pasta, para iniciar, você precisa executar `npm install`. Isso vai instalar todas dependências contidas no `package.json`.  Então, quando você executar `mimosa watch` ou `mimosa build` a primeira vez, Mimosa vai instalar qualquer módulo de Mimosa necessário.

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Comment: O próprio autor do Mimosa veio aqui responder. Que legal! (Mimosa's own author came here to answer. Cool!) :-)

Comment: You said "when you run mimosa watch or mimosa watch the first time", is that really what you meant? BTW, I didn't know Mimosa, it looks like a really great tool. I'm considering switching from grunt.

Comment: First, I apologize for answering in the wrong language again, but its my only option!!!  I meant "mimosa watch" and "mimosa build".  If you do attempt to switch from grunt, I'd love to hear about any trouble you have.  I don't want to break any more language rules than I already have, so if you have specific questions you can reach me via a Mimosa GitHub issue, Twitter (@mimosajs) or the Google Group.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Taí... o cenário é mais complexo do que no composer/PHP, pois temos o `npm` para instalar as dependências declaradas no `package.json` do esqueleto, e depois Mimosa por sua vez instala tanto as suas próprias dependências (parafernália que precisa para rodar), quanto as demais declaradas no projeto do esqueleto, seja na configuração específica `mimosa-config.coffee`, seja nas demais, como por exemplo `bower.json` (Mimosa irá executar Bower, que irá instalar tais dependências). É um "ecossistema" sofisticado!